# Stomach Virus : How does it affect the bacteria of the intestines?

Tags: stomach

When you have a stomach virus and it causes extreme bowel movements to the point of almost pure stomach acid, does this kill off the bacteria in our intestinal tracks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since the pH and the conditions are different in the different compartments (stomach, small intestine, colon) of the bowel.
See this figure (taken from this [website](http://altered-states.net/barry/update178/)) for the differences:

[image]

There are not that much bacteria in the stomach, so even even nothing else than acidic stuff comes out, the bacteria are not affected. And even when you have a severe diarrhea, there are still enough bacteria left to keep it colonized.